# Why my website become unresponsive when tsparticles in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

I have an react app...
There I use tsparticles...
I configure tsparticles in a component and use this component inside main.jsx....
My tsparticles componenet and main.jsx code is bellow:

tsparticles component:

```
import Particles, { initParticlesEngine } from "@tsparticles/react";
import { loadSlim } from "@tsparticles/slim";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TsParticales = () => {
  const [init, setInit] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    initParticlesEngine(async (engine) => {
      // you can initiate the tsParticles instance (engine) here, adding custom shapes or presets
      // this loads the tsparticles package bundle, it's the easiest method for getting everything ready
      // starting from v2 you can add only the features you need reducing the bundle size
      //await loadAll(engine);
      //await loadFull(engine);
      await loadSlim(engine);
      //await loadBasic(engine);
    }).then(() => {
      setInit(true);
    });
  }, []);

  const particlesLoaded = (container) => {
    console.log(container);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {init ? (
        <Particles
          id="tsparticles"
          particlesLoaded={particlesLoaded}
          options={{
            autoPlay: true,
            background: {
              color: {
                value: "#000",
              },
              image: "",
              position: "",
              repeat: "",
              size: "",
              opacity: 1,
            },
            backgroundMask: {
              composite: "destination-out",
              cover: {
                color: {
                  value: "#fff",
                },
                opacity: 1,
              },
              enable: false,
            },
            clear: true,
            defaultThemes: {},
            delay: 0,
            fullScreen: {
              enable: true,
              zIndex: -1,
            },
            detectRetina: true,
            duration: 0,
            fpsLimit: 120,
            interactivity: {
              detectsOn: "window",
              events: {
                onClick: {
                  enable: false,
                  mode: [],
                },
                onDiv: {
                  selectors: [],
                  enable: false,
                  mode: [],
                  type: "circle",
                },
                onHover: {
                  enable: true,
                  mode: "trail",
                  parallax: {
                    enable: false,
                    force: 2,
                    smooth: 10,
                  },
                },
                resize: {
                  delay: 0.5,
                  enable: true,
                },
              },
              modes: {
                trail: {
                  delay: 0.005,
                  pauseOnStop: true,
                  quantity: 5,
                  particles: {
                    color: {
                      value: "#ff0000",
                      animation: {
                        enable: true,
                        speed: 400,
                        sync: true,
                      },
                    },
                    collisions: {
                      enable: false,
                    },
                    links: {
                      enable: false,
                    },
                    move: {
                      outModes: {
                        default: "destroy",
                      },
                      speed: 2,
                    },
                    size: {
                      value: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 5,
                      },
                      animation: {
                        enable: true,
                        speed: 5,
                        sync: true,
                        startValue: "min",
                        destroy: "max",
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
                attract: {
                  distance: 200,
                  duration: 0.4,
                  easing: "ease-out-quad",
                  factor: 1,
                  maxSpeed: 50,
                  speed: 1,
                },
                bounce: {
                  distance: 200,
                },
                bubble: {
                  distance: 200,
                  duration: 0.4,
                  mix: false,
                  divs: {
                    distance: 200,
                    duration: 0.4,
                    mix: false,
                    selectors: [],
                  },
                },
                connect: {
                  distance: 80,
                  links: {
                    opacity: 0.5,
                  },
                  radius: 60,
                },
                grab: {
                  distance: 100,
                  links: {
                    blink: false,
                    consent: false,
                    opacity: 1,
                  },
                },
                push: {
                  default: true,
                  groups: [],
                  quantity: 4,
                },
                remove: {
                  quantity: 2,
                },
                repulse: {
                  distance: 200,
                  duration: 0.4,
                  factor: 100,
                  speed: 1,
                  maxSpeed: 50,
                  easing: "ease-out-quad",
                  divs: {
                    distance: 200,
                    duration: 0.4,
                    factor: 100,
                    speed: 1,
                    maxSpeed: 50,
                    easing: "ease-out-quad",
                    selectors: [],
                  },
                },
                slow: {
                  factor: 3,
                  radius: 200,
                },
                light: {
                  area: {
                    gradient: {
                      start: {
                        value: "#ffffff",
                      },
                      stop: {
                        value: "#000000",
                      },
                    },
                    radius: 1000,
                  },
                  shadow: {
                    color: {
                      value: "#000000",
                    },
                    length: 2000,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            manualParticles: [],
            particles: {
              bounce: {
                horizontal: {
                  value: 1,
                },
                vertical: {
                  value: 1,
                },
              },
              collisions: {
                absorb: {
                  speed: 2,
                },
                bounce: {
                  horizontal: {
                    value: 1,
                  },
                  vertical: {
                    value: 1,
                  },
                },
                enable: false,
                maxSpeed: 50,
                mode: "bounce",
                overlap: {
                  enable: true,
                  retries: 0,
                },
              },
              color: {
                value: "#ff0000",
                animation: {
                  h: {
                    count: 0,
                    enable: true,
                    speed: 50,
                    decay: 0,
                    delay: 0,
                    sync: false,
                    offset: 0,
                  },
                  s: {
                    count: 0,
                    enable: false,
                    speed: 1,
                    decay: 0,
                    delay: 0,
                    sync: true,
                    offset: 0,
                  },
                  l: {
                    count: 0,
                    enable: false,
                    speed: 1,
                    decay: 0,
                    delay: 0,
                    sync: true,
                    offset: 0,
                  },
                },
              },
              effect: {
                close: true,
                fill: true,
                options: {},
                type: [],
              },
              groups: {},
              move: {
                angle: {
                  offset: 0,
                  value: 90,
                },
                attract: {
                  distance: 200,
                  enable: false,
                  rotate: {
                    x: 3000,
                    y: 3000,
                  },
                },
                center: {
                  x: 50,
                  y: 50,
                  mode: "percent",
                  radius: 0,
                },
                decay: 0,
                distance: {},
                direction: "none",
                drift: 0,
                enable: true,
                gravity: {
                  acceleration: 9.81,
                  enable: false,
                  inverse: false,
                  maxSpeed: 50,
                },
                path: {
                  clamp: true,
                  delay: {
                    value: 0,
                  },
                  enable: false,
                  options: {},
                },
                outModes: {
                  default: "out",
                  bottom: "out",
                  left: "out",
                  right: "out",
                  top: "out",
                },
                random: false,
                size: false,
                speed: 2,
                spin: {
                  acceleration: 0,
                  enable: false,
                },
                straight: false,
                trail: {
                  enable: false,
                  length: 10,
                  fill: {},
                },
                vibrate: false,
                warp: false,
              },
              number: {
                density: {
                  enable: true,
                  width: 1920,
                  height: 1080,
                },
                limit: {
                  mode: "delete",
                  value: 0,
                },
                value: 100,
              },
              opacity: {
                value: {
                  min: 0.3,
                  max: 0.8,
                },
                animation: {
                  count: 0,
                  enable: true,
                  speed: 0.5,
                  decay: 0,
                  delay: 0,
                  sync: false,
                  mode: "auto",
                  startValue: "random",
                  destroy: "none",
                },
              },
              reduceDuplicates: false,
              shadow: {
                blur: 0,
                color: {
                  value: "#000",
                },
                enable: false,
                offset: {
                  x: 0,
                  y: 0,
                },
              },
              shape: {
                close: true,
                fill: true,
                options: {},
                type: "circle",
              },
              size: {
                value: {
                  min: 1,
                  max: 3,
                },
                animation: {
                  count: 0,
                  enable: true,
                  speed: 3,
                  decay: 0,
                  delay: 0,
                  sync: false,
                  mode: "auto",
                  startValue: "random",
                  destroy: "none",
                },
              },
              stroke: {
                width: 0,
              },
              zIndex: {
                value: 0,
                opacityRate: 1,
                sizeRate: 1,
                velocityRate: 1,
              },
              destroy: {
                bounds: {},
                mode: "none",
                split: {
                  count: 1,
                  factor: {
                    value: 3,
                  },
                  rate: {
                    value: {
                      min: 4,
                      max: 9,
                    },
                  },
                  sizeOffset: true,
                  particles: {},
                },
              },
              roll: {
                darken: {
                  enable: false,
                  value: 0,
                },
                enable: false,
                enlighten: {
                  enable: false,
                  value: 0,
                },
                mode: "vertical",
                speed: 25,
              },
              tilt: {
                value: 0,
                animation: {
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 0,
                  decay: 0,
                  sync: false,
                },
                direction: "clockwise",
                enable: false,
              },
              twinkle: {
                lines: {
                  enable: false,
                  frequency: 0.05,
                  opacity: 1,
                },
                particles: {
                  enable: false,
                  frequency: 0.05,
                  opacity: 1,
                },
              },
              wobble: {
                distance: 5,
                enable: false,
                speed: {
                  angle: 50,
                  move: 10,
                },
              },
              life: {
                count: 0,
                delay: {
                  value: 0,
                  sync: false,
                },
                duration: {
                  value: 0,
                  sync: false,
                },
              },
              rotate: {
                value: 0,
                animation: {
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 0,
                  decay: 0,
                  sync: false,
                },
                direction: "clockwise",
                path: false,
              },
              orbit: {
                animation: {
                  count: 0,
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 1,
                  decay: 0,
                  delay: 0,
                  sync: false,
                },
                enable: false,
                opacity: 1,
                rotation: {
                  value: 45,
                },
                width: 1,
              },
              links: {
                blink: false,
                color: {
                  value: "random",
                },
                consent: false,
                distance: 100,
                enable: true,
                frequency: 1,
                opacity: 1,
                shadow: {
                  blur: 5,
                  color: {
                    value: "#000",
                  },
                  enable: false,
                },
                triangles: {
                  enable: false,
                  frequency: 1,
                },
                width: 1,
                warp: false,
              },
              repulse: {
                value: 0,
                enabled: false,
                distance: 1,
                duration: 1,
                factor: 1,
                speed: 1,
              },
            },
            pauseOnBlur: true,
            pauseOnOutsideViewport: true,
            responsive: [],
            smooth: false,
            style: {},
            themes: [],
            zLayers: 100,
            emitters: [],
            motion: {
              disable: false,
              reduce: {
                factor: 4,
                value: true,
              },
            },
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <h1>loading</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TsParticales;
```

main.jsx component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Router from "./Routes/Route.jsx";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import TsParticales from "./Components/TsParticales/TsParticales.jsx";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <RouterProvider router={Router} />
      <TsParticales /> 
      <Toaster />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

When I use TsParticles and RouterProvider both component the website give an alert website unresponsive..
But if I comment any one of them website work properly...

Here is the github repo link : https://github.com/mdsayel111/Problem

I expect that the tsparticles will be show a backgroun animation in the website...